# Mac OS X 10.6.8 not storing password in system profile - used for pre-authentication to the wireless network

Tags: network, snow-leopard, wifi

Running 300 MacBooks with Mac OS X 10.6.8.

When logged on as a local admin I can connect to WiFi, I save the connection in the system profile, allowing pre-authentication before users attempt to log on.

This has been working fine for nearly a year. Now the system profile requires re-entering the WiFi password before connecting after logon, restart, even turning airport off and back on.

What could be causing this? DNS? IAS/Radius? DHCP?

Windows clients just work.

Any ideas would be great, the users are back on Monday!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you haven't enabled the security settings in System Preferences -> Network -> Wi-Fi (Airport?) -> Advanced -> Wi-Fi: "Require administrator password to:"...

It may also help to examine log files on the computers that are having the issues. Best place to start is probably the log at /var/log/system.log. If you're using RADIUS, it may help to enable EAPOL logging:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.eapolclient LogFlags -int 1
```

To disable EAPOL logging, you can perform this command:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.eapolclient LogFlags -int 0
```

You may need to reboot after applying this command. The resulting log file should be located at /var/log/eapolclient.< interface >.log (e.g., eapolclient.en1.log)

Comment: Hi Eddie,Thanks for your reply and the helpful suggestions. I will give it a try and see what the logs reveal. I imported the same profile manually (from USB key) to all the MacBooks and everything was fine. Been using the same profile since May with no issues...